# Заготовка TCP сервера

Tags: сервисы, клиент-сервер, tcp

Мне нужна программа, которая работает как TCP сервер, т.е. управляет соединениями, распределяет нагрузку и так далее -- но логику чтобы можно было написать самому, можно на скриптовом языке или с использованием не очень сложного API.

Написать сервер целиком для меня -- очень сложная задача, поэтому ищу полуфабричные варианты.

Встречали ли вы нечто подобное? Расскажите, пожалуйста :)

---

**UPD:** Попробую переформулировать вопрос.

Мне хочется изобрести сетевой протокол прикладного уровня для своей программы. Мне нужно написать сервер, но хочется чтобы получилось попроще и побыстрее. Мне это видится так: есть программа-сервер `SERVER.EXE`, которая будет:

- прослушивать указанный TCP порт, например `1234` и принимать входящие соединения
- параллельно обслуживать подключенных клиентов
- позволять мне реализовать логику на каком-либо скриптовом языке и будет выполнять её для каждого клиента

*Вопрос: есть ли такая программа, и как она называется?*

Comment: @tabby_cat, что именно Вы понимаете под управлением соединениями и распределением нагрузки (что конкретно и между чем распределять)?

Comment: @tabby_cat, если тупо вызывать скрипт, связывая его stdin/stdout с пришедшим TCP соединением, то есть. 

Например в линуксе, ncat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на ноде можно написать, простых примеров - масса, [например здесь](http://www.nodebeginner.ru/#a-basic-http-server)

Comment: Спасибо, на первый взгляд именно то, что мне нужно ^^

Comment: очень настойчиво рекомендую не искать "готовое", поскольку обязательно наступит момент, когда его "готовость" начнет мешать. Нода - весьма лояльная к новичкам технология, ссылка выше - отменный, легкий учебник, достаточный для понимания принципа построения серверных приложений. Не забудьте отметить мой ответ как лучший ;)

Answer (score 0):

эм, apache, nginx. Bash скрипты слушать порты. вариантов то море.

- на С++ можно написать что-то подобное, строк в 30-40. Непонятно зачем это нужно.

Comment: @Shrek, а как сделать так, чтобы Apache слушал TCP порт (не HTTP)? Поделитесь пожалуйста..

Comment: http-это протокол и tcp это тоже протокол, а не порт!

Ты отправляешь данные на пример:

>127.0.0.1:80

>127.0.0.1:1280

>127.0.0.1:8080

Прошу.
Ты отправляешь запрос на сервер по ip 127.0.0.1 на 80,1280,8080 порты. в чем проблема?

Не путай протоколы и порты.

Я же в ответе написал 

> непонятно зачем это нужно, что куда будет отправляться и как отдаваться, и все прочее.

Распределение нагрузки может взять и nginx, понимаешь в вопросе всё ооочень не явно.

Comment: @Shrek, вы меня не так поняли. Я хотел спросить каким образом заставил Apache принимать **ЛЮБЫЕ** соединение выше TCP. Не обязательно им должен быть HTTP. Было бы здорово если бы Apache это умел..

Comment: Когда ТС удосужится правильно поставить вопрос, вернемся к "ассемблеру" :)